# Include a different button icon when hover

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

I have this liquid code:

```
<a href="{{ section.settings.button_link }}" class="btn--rounded">
    {% include 'icon-btn--rounded' %}
    <div class="link-label">{{ section.settings.button_label }}</div>
</a>
```

And when the button is hover, I need to show a different icon, for example:

```
{% include 'icon-btn--white' %}
```

I now that I can use `display: none` for that, but how can I dynamically change between buttons when I hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use CSS to show the different icons on hover.

Liquid is a language that loads before the DOM is ready. This means that once you see content of the page the liquid code has finished its execution and it will not fire again until a reload of the page.

Or to say it in developer terms - you are trying to load a back-end function via the front-end, which is a big "no-no".

CSS and JS can't interact with liquid, but liquid can interact with them. Or to say it more simply you can create javascript and css code using Liquid, but you can't create liquid code using JS and CSS.

In addition includes are deprecated and you should be using render instead.

Here is the code that you should use:

```
<a href="{{ section.settings.button_link }}" class="btn--rounded">
    <div class="icon">
        {% render 'icon-btn--rounded' %}
    </div><!-- /.icon -->
    <div class="icon icon--hover">
        {% render 'icon-btn--white' %}
    </div><!-- /.icon -->
    <div class="link-label">{{ section.settings.button_label }}</div>
</a>

<style>
    .icon--hover {
        display: none;
    }

    .btn--rounded:hover .icon {
        display: none;
    }
    .btn--rounded:hover .icon--hover {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```